# How do I populate a select box using an ajax call which returns a list of strings using dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to populate a select box using `dojo`. My Spring controller returns an `arraylist` of `string`, I want to get all the strings into my select box.

```
    var currencyStore = new RequestMemory({
                target: "getCurrency"
        });
    var os = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: currencyStore });
    var currencyCombo = new Select({
            store: os
        }, "currency").startup();
```

But the select box is empty with the above code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would try feeding your array into a `Store` and then giving the store to a `Select`.  See the example provided here.  I will try to provide a permanent example as an answer. [A Select Fed By A Store](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/Select.html#a-select-fed-by-a-store)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using `dojo/Store` and `dijit/form/Select`

Let me first state that I have no real experience with Spring so I am going off of your statement that you have an `ArrayList` of `String`s and you want them to be options in a `dijit/form/Select`.  If you don't mean to use dijit widgets or that you mean that you want to use a regular `<select>` tag with no dojo backing, then you are dealing with another solution.

That being said, you can use the example that I linked in my comment above: [A Select Fed By A Store](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/Select.html#a-select-fed-by-a-store) in order to more easily accomplish putting your data set into a `<select>` and be able to leverage other niceties of the widget.

```js
require([
  "dijit/form/Select",
  "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
  "dojo/store/Memory",
  "dojo/_base/array",
  "dojo/dom",
  "dojo/html",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(
  Select,
  ObjectStore,
  Memory,
  array,
  dom,
  html
) {
  "use strict";

  /*
  We used the domReady! plugin so this code runs
  after the DOM has finished loading
  */

  // Predefine
  var strings, idStrings, store, objectStore, select;

  /*
  Strings is going to be the "arrayList of Strings" that you
  mention that you receive from your spring controller
  */
  strings = [
    "hello",
    "world",
    "foo",
    "bar"
  ];

  /*
  We are going to map your String array so that it has an 
  "id" property and a "label" property which will get used
  by the Store and the Select
  */
  idStrings = array.map(strings, function(str, index) {
    return {
      id: index,
      label: str
    };
  });

  // Make a Memory Store
  store = new Memory({
    data: idStrings
  });

  // Make an ObjectStore from the Memory
  objectStore = new ObjectStore({
    objectStore: store
  });

  // Create the Select and set its store to the one we just made
  select = new Select({
    name: "testSelect",
    store: objectStore
  }, "testSelect");

  // We need to run startup on programatically created widgets
  select.startup();

  // Add change listener for funzies
  select.on("change", function() {
    // Get the label from the store by the value of this Select
    var label = store.get(this.get("value")).label;

    // Set the innerHTML of our logger
    html.set(dom.byId("logger"), label);
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Include the dijit claro theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">

<!-- Set our dojoConfig -->
<script>
  var dojoConfig = {
    parseOnLoad: false,
    isDebug: true,
    async: 1
  };
</script>
<!-- Include the dojo 1.10.4 CDN -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>


<body class="claro">
  <main>
    <!-- This Select is going to be replaced by our widget -->
    <select id="testSelect"></select>

    <!-- We're going to put output in this div -->
    <div role="log" id="logger"></div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Additionally, if you don't want to use the `dijit/form/Select` you could just insert options into the `<select>` yourself with either native JavaScript methods like `document.createElement("option");` and then fit the attributes on manually, but since you've already used the bandwidth to load dojo, you might as well make things easier on yourself by using its DOM manipulation methods such as `dojo/domConstruct.create()`.

### Without `dijit/form/Select`

```
require([
    "dojo/_base/array",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function (
    array,
    dom,
    domConstruct,
) {
    "use strict";

    var strings, select;

    // We have our strings
    strings = [
        "hello",
        "world",
        "foo",
        "bar"
    ];

    // Get our select
    select = dom.byId("testSelect");

    // Iterate each string and put it into an option under our select
    array.forEach(strings, function (str, index) {
        domConstruct.create("option", {
            innerHTML: str,
            value: index
        }, select);
    });
});
```

---

### Side Note

You probably don't need to use `dojo/_base/array`.  I do so out of habit for supporting old browsers and since we're already using dojo.  Also, you probably have your own setup for where modules go and are, hopefully, using some sort of build layer rather than using the CDN so you should refactor this so that it is not just some inline script as I have done in this example.

Comment: I stucked here:
 idStrings = array.map(strings, function(str, index) {
    return {
      id: index,
      label: str
    };
  });
 Thanks..